# asp.net gridview doesn't display data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCS"].ConnectionString);      
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connb.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.Users;", conn);
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(tb);
        tb.AcceptChanges();
        GridView1.DataSource = tb;
        GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}
```

This is my code in C# asp.net application. I want to display SQL table in gridview.

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
  <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="lastname" HeaderText="lastname" />
  <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
</Columns>
```

IT shows empty gridview(When I press button1). It doesn't shows any error message.  Connection string works, SQL command affects rows, But it still doesn't show any data on gridview!!!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking that there is actually data in the table when it is being data bound?

Comment: Yes I have tried but in windows forms.

Comment: Is it correct id `GridView1`

Comment: Have you tried debugging your actual web page to ensure that button1 is correctly hooked up to the method, and to ensure that there are rows in `tb`?

Comment: See my answer. i hopes it may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20855275/2218635

Comment: Button1 is working well. I have tried to do another things on pressing button1 and it worked.  Yes  tb contains rows!

Comment: @user2971569 What you tried? did you set AutoGenerateColumns="false" in your grid view? can i see that? please post your full gridview code.

Comment: dear please check the datafield="" have the same name as columns in the datatabel or in the database

Answer (score 1):

You could be getting exception in `DataBind()` - use a `try-catch` block. This could happen due to a missing column in the `DataTable` that is being used in a bound field.

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

   SqlConnectionStringBuilder connb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCS"].ConnectionString);
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connb.ConnectionString))
   {
    try
    {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.Users;", conn);
      DataTable tb = new DataTable();

      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

      da.Fill(tb);
      tb.AcceptChanges();
      GridView1.DataSource = tb;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text. = "a";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }     
   }           
}
```

Comment: gridview1.rows[0].cells[0].text    _ it was extra(I just tried. I wanted to see what would happen). I deleted this but here isn't problem. problem is that datagridview doesn't show any data which is in my sql server.

Comment: I removed that already, check my updated answer. you will get the exception in catch, put a break point in catch block.

Comment: You probably need to put the try catch in side using block, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I tried to use try catch inside using block, but it doesn't work. Gridview doesn't show any data.

Comment: Can you see data in datatable after fill method?

Comment: It is already in my site and I am just changing the code from visual studio(File-> open -> web site). Can it be a problem?

Comment: Did you publish the site make a library? if not then save the page. You can ensure but putting some syntax error on page but be careful if it is live site.

Comment: Make some change in code to check if you get that change in the rendered page, or you would need to publish it again

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(ds);

GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your query never gets executed

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ()
```

This should have happened before this line

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should set **`AutoGenerateColumns="false"`**, if you  want to bind specify column.Please check it
- And also need to check have you set `visible="false"` or `style="display:none"` in your gridview
- And check `DataField` must matched the table `column` name

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was getting data in the datasource and the GridView wasn't showing up at all.  I had AutoGenerateColumns = "true" in the Gridview definition on the page.  For some reason, when I set up a breakpoint and looked at the properties of the Gridview in the code behind, it was still set to false.  I set it to true in the code behind before setting the Gridview equal to the datasource and doing the databind.  That worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.Users;", conn);
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);      
       ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds, "usersdata");
       GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["usersdata"];
       GridView1.DataBind();
```